# Inputbox NumericKey and Password char Firemonkey Delphi xe5

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

i want use numericKeypad and Password input on "inputbox" Function.
android and ios. (Firemonkey Delphi XE5)

```
eg. str:=inputbox('pass','pass','pass')
```

but only show on device multiple keyboard layout.
Please solution.
Thanks...

Comment: i dont get why people dont take the time to ask a real question where its clear whats the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InputBox` doesn't offer a choice of which keyboard you use, whether it's the [FMX.Dialogs.InputBox](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Dialogs.InputBox) or [VCL.Dialogs.InputBox](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.Dialogs.InputBox) version. It's a standardized function that uses the standard keyboard layout.

If you want different behavior, use a different method to get the input. Design your own form that supplies the specialized behavior and show it to get the input from the user.